# Nativescript Angular RadListView not working on fetching data from a remote server

Tags: angular, nativescript

I've implemented, following the examples from git a RadListView and is working fine when data it's fetched from a .json file (like on the git example)

Instead when I go further and tried to fetch data from a remote server instead the RadListView result to be empty.

So, what I'm doing wrong? Below a snippet from my source code:

```
private initDataItems() {

        // NOT WORKING: Fetching data from remote
        // see the implementation of getAllRankings() below
        this.rankingService.getAllRankings().subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray<DataItem>();
                // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
                for (let i = 0; i < res.queryresult.length; i++) {
                    if (androidApplication) {

                        this._sourceDataItems.push(new DataItem(i, posts.names[i],
                            "This is item description",
                            posts.titles[i], posts.text[i], "res://" + posts.images[i].toLowerCase()));

                        console.log(this._sourceDataItems);
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        /*
        // WORKING: Fetching data from .json file (post.json)
        this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray<DataItem>();
        for (let i = 0; i < posts.names.length; i++) {
            if (androidApplication) {
                this._sourceDataItems.push(new DataItem(i, posts.names[i],
                    "This is item description",
                    posts.titles[i], posts.text[i], "res://" + posts.images[i].toLowerCase()));
            } else {
                this._sourceDataItems.push(new DataItem(i,
                    posts.names[i], "This is item description",
                    posts.titles[i], posts.text[i], "res://" + posts.images[i]));
            }
        }
        */
    }
}
```

where getAllRankings() looks like:

```
getAllRankings() {
        return this.http.get<{ queryresult: any }>("http://api.dev.blabla.com/posts");
    }
```

Comment: The endpoint is inaccessible, please share a valid endpoint or add sample response that will help us understand how your data will look like.

Comment: The end-point is not relevant as is used only counting the number of records fetched. Nevertheless, the end-point return (lenght=2): {"querryresult":[{"id":1,"idUser":"sasqwq12121","consecutiveLines":1,"indexItemClicked":1,"listIndexItemsClicked":"1","nrcupons":11,"nrlines":11,"nrprize":1,"nrsprize":1,"nrstickets":1,"nrtickets":1},{"id":2,"idUser":"rtrtrfgfgfgf","consecutiveLines":1,"indexItemClicked":1,"listIndexItemsClicked":"1","nrcupons":11,"nrlines":11,"nrprize":1,"nrsprize":1,"nrstickets":1,"nrtickets":1}]}

Comment: More I ensure the  console.log(this._sourceDataItems); is printing correctly the two DataItem(...) object but those two items are not printed by RadListView.

Comment: Instead, de-commenting the source code below: ... // WORKING: Fetching data from .json file (post.json) the RadListView is going to print the data from posts.json  file

So the real issue is when fetching the data remotely so it is something with RadListView which do not succeed to print data remotely fetched.

Comment: Why you are accessing posts[i] which is not a valid variable while inside the loop of query result.

Comment: @Manoj posts variable is also NOT relevant in this discussion. RadListView is not printing the DataItem objects even I substitute posts with static string values like:

this._sourceDataItems.push(new DataItem(1, "TestName", "This is item description", "Test title", "Test texts", "res://blabla"));

Comment: I'm not sure why you might want to post the controller code if you think issue is with template. Possibly it could be anywhere, unless you share complete code that can reproduce the issue, it may not be possible to debug any further.

Answer (score 1):

Create your array object at the start so that your template can render something. Then, because the callback from your network call will be outside of the angular zone, put it back inside.

```js
import { ..., NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor( ..., private zone: NgZone) {
  ...
}

private initDataItems() {

        this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray<DataItem>();

        // see the implementation of getAllRankings() below
        this.rankingService.getAllRankings().subscribe(
            (res) => {
                // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
                for (let i = 0; i < res.queryresult.length; i++) {
                    if (androidApplication) {

                        this.zone.run(() => {
                            this._sourceDataItems.push(new DataItem(i, posts.names[i],
                                "This is item description",
                                posts.titles[i], posts.text[i], "res://" + posts.images[i].toLowerCase()));

                            console.log(this._sourceDataItems);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Alternatively, you could probably do something with the change detector, too.

**Note**: To avoid pushing one at a time and triggering a bunch of sequential changes to be detected, you'd be better off using a spread push.

```js
this._sourceDataItems.push(...res.queryresult.map((res) => new DataItem( ... )));
```